# Mocking classes or global functions in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking, mockito

I am trying to understand how mocking works with dart and mockito.
Image I have the below declarations:

```
void foo(){}
```

and similarly a class

```
class BarClass {
   void bar(){}
}
```

and then my widget accesses the first one directly as `foo();` and the second one as `BarClass()`.

What would be the way to mock these two? Should I be accessing them through something like getit to mock them properly or is there actually a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mock classes by creating a new class that implements the functionality of your old one using the [mockito package](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito)

example code:

```
class MockBarClass extends Mock implements BarClass {}
```

you can mock methods of your `BarClass` in the following way:

```
final mock = MockBarClass();
when(() => mock.boo()).thenAnswer((_) {
    // your mocked response
    print("hello world");
});
```

---

you can mock functions that are in no classes the same way:

```
when(boo()).thenReturn();
```

[source by Remi Rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582785/12165405)

---

#### additional information if you ask yourself what's the difference between `.thenReturn(...)` and `.thenAnswer((){...})`:

I recommend reading this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36627077/12165405 (even though it's for java, the same applies for that flutter package)

Comment: Yes, I know I can mock classes, but how do you mock a class *or* a global function for a widget test, that was the question. Is there any other way than passing the class/function as a parameter into the widget?

Comment: oh okay! 
That is one downside of using `getIt` instead of `Provider` or something else. But what you can do (without dependency injection) , is to override the registered Service/Class in your `setUpAll` function of your test with a *mocked class*. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246565/12165405 .
Unfortunately I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: yep, thank you, I think it's more or less possible with getit but without it is not as far as I understand

Comment: This is not working